# awk regex for nested big brackets

Tags: regex, awk

I have a structure like this:

```
label1 {
   label1_1 {

      item1_1_1: "value1_1_1";
      label1_1_2:{ item1_1_2_1: "value1_1_2_1";};

      item1_1_3: "value1_1_3";
   };

   label1_2 {...};
   ...
};

label2 {
   item2_1: "value2_1";
   label2_1:{
      item2_1_1: "value2_1_1";
      ...
   };
};
```

The section could be in one line or multiple lines, and empty line presentable. I'm trying to use awk to get any section with given label name,

```
section=$(awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' "/($2)\s(\{([^{}]|(?R)|\n)*\})/" $1)
```

where the $1 is file name, $2 is label name. It works if happens no empty line in the section, for example "label2", but faild by others.

What's the correct regex I should use?

Comment: `awk` doesn't support PCRE recursive patterns

Comment: To expand on @anubhava's statement - there is no regexp supported by awk that can do what you want. You can do what you want in awk, of course, just not with a regexp. So - do you want an awk solution or a solution that is a regexp? Also, if `{` or `}` or newlines can occur within the quoted strings, e.g. `item1_1_1: "value{1_1_1}"` then include those cases in your sample input/output as they make the job very different from otherwise. Think about and include what might be hard for a script to deal with, not just the easy cases.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I'm not familiar with awk too much, not sure how to embedded tst.awk into my bash script, as I hope everything could be in one piece. If awk is too difficult to do it, we can use other command, do you know which command can achieve this goal?

Comment: Great! Ed. Your solution works! but not perfect for label name contains space or quotation, but it's blamed to myself not gave a good example, if you are able to kindly update your script will be perfect! BTW, I'm not going to deal with text for rest of my life, this is just for temporary, but your script will goes to my personal magic stuffs inventory.  ;-)

Comment: Replaced (\<([[:alnum:]_]+):?\s*{[^{}]+};) with (\<([[:alnum:]."-]+):?\s*{[^{}]+};), now the script is able to recognize lab-el"2.2", but can't contains space, even doesn't work for (\<([[:alnum:][:space:]."-]+):?\s*{[^{}]+};), actually my label forms: label-1 "2.2". Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do what you want, assuming neither `{` nor `}` can occur within quoted strings and using GNU awk 4.* for a couple of extensions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="^$" }
{
    tmp = $0
    while ( match(tmp,/(\<([[:alnum:]_]+):?\s*{[^{}]+};)/,a) ) {
        start[a[2]] = RSTART
        lgth[a[2]]  = RLENGTH
        tmp = substr(tmp,1,RSTART-1) sprintf("%*s",length(a[1]),"") substr(tmp,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
label in start { print substr($0,start[label],lgth[label]) }
```

.

```
$ awk -v label='label2' -f tst.awk file
label2 {
   item2_1: "value2_1";
   label2_1:{
      item2_1_1: "value2_1_1";
      ...
   };
};

$ awk -v label='label1_1' -f tst.awk file
label1_1 {

      item1_1_1: "value1_1_1";
      label1_1_2:{ item1_1_2_1: "value1_1_2_1";};

      item1_1_3: "value1_1_3";
   };

$ awk -v label='label1_1_2' -f tst.awk file
label1_1_2:{ item1_1_2_1: "value1_1_2_1";};
```

You can call awk as either `awk -f scriptfile inputfile` or `awk 'script' inputfile` so to use the above awk script inline instead of stored in a file is just:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS="^$" }
{
    tmp = $0
    while ( match(tmp,/(\<([[:alnum:]_]+):?\s*{[^{}]+};)/,a) ) {
        start[a[2]] = RSTART
        lgth[a[2]]  = RLENGTH
        tmp = substr(tmp,1,RSTART-1) sprintf("%*s",length(a[1]),"") substr(tmp,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
label in start { print substr($0,start[label],lgth[label]) }
' file
```